# Set the sourceRange of Data Validation to an array of values

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a social media outreach tracker. I want to create a drop-down list of the contact name. The problem is that I have two sources of names on two different sheets.

I wrote a script that pulls the names from the two different sources and combines them to a single array.

I was hoping to set the source range as that array.

Here is my code:

```
function setDataValid_(range, sourceRange) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true)
    .build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit() {
  var auditionsSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var castingDirectorsTab = auditionsSheet.getSheetByName("Casting Directors");
  var contactsTab = auditionsSheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var socialMediaOutreachTab = auditionsSheet.getSheetByName("Social Media Outreach");
  var lastRowCD = castingDirectorsTab.getLastRow();
  var lastRowContacts = contactsTab.getLastRow();  
  var activeCell = socialMediaOutreachTab.getActiveCell();
  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();

  // get data
  var castingDirectorNameData = castingDirectorsTab.getRange(2, 1, lastRowCD, 1).getValues();
  var contactNameData = contactsTab.getRange(2, 1, lastRowContacts, 1).getValues();  

  //get name data to a single arrays
  var castingDirectorName = [];
  castingDirectorNameData.forEach(function(yr) {
    castingDirectorName.push(yr[0]);
  });

  var contactName = [];
  contactNameData.forEach(function(yr) {
     contactName.push(yr[0]);
  });

  // get rid of the empty bits in the arrays
  for (var x = castingDirectorName.length-1; x > 0; x--)  {
    if ( castingDirectorName[x][0] === undefined ) {
        castingDirectorName.splice(  x, 1 )
    }
  }

  for (var x = contactName.length-1; x > 0; x--)  {
    if ( contactName[x][0] === undefined ) {
      contactName.splice(  x, 1 )
    }
  }

  //combine two data sources for data validation
  var combinedNames = [];
  combinedNames.push(castingDirectorName + contactName);

  Logger.log (combinedNames);
  Logger.log( typeof combinedNames);

  // data validation set up and build
  if (activeColumn == 1 && auditionsSheet.getName() == "Social Media Outreach") {
    var range = auditionsSheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), activeColumn +1);
    var sourceRange = combinedNames;
    setDataValid_(range, sourceRange)
  }
}
```

When I enter a date in Col A on Social Media Outreach, nothing happens in Col 2.

I was using an existing working nested data validation script I have but the sourceRange pulls from a sheet based on the value in the active cell. Here is that code:

```
function setDataValid_(range, sourceRange) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true)
    .build();
   range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit() {
  var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

  // data validation for Auditions Tab Projet Type to Project Details 
  if (aColumn == 9 && aSheet.getName() == 'Auditions') {
    var range = aSheet.getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('RefTables!' + aCell.getValue())
    setDataValid_(range, sourceRange)
  }
}
```

For this script when I select from the data validation drop-down, a new data validation comes up in the next col with the appropriate secondary data validation.

So the question is, can the source range be set to an array or do I need to put the names back into my sheet to reference a la the second script.

I've looked through the documentation and searched and can't find an answer. I'm relatively new to GAS and am not sure of all the inner workings of the data validation builder.

Comment: I've updated the first part to                                          function setDataValid_(range, sourceRange) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(sourceRange, true).build();
   range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
 But it still isn't working

Comment: Provide [mcve] for your comment.

Comment: `requireValueInRange` needs a `Range`. It isn't the only `require....` method though. Also, make sure you understand the difference between simple and installed triggers. [`Edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54625884/edit) your question to reflect your efforts to understand and resolve the issue you face.